# How to disable web inspector for a TVML based release app?

Tags: javascript, tvos

I'm developing a tvos app based on TVML and TVMLJS, safari web inspector can help me debug javascript, but in release version it will leak the source code, how to disallow web inspector to find and connect to my app?
I see most released apps in tv appstore was not able to connect and debug with safari web inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Production applications (on Mac, iOS, tvOS) distributed via App Store cannot be remotely inspected.

Comment: Thanks, but from my test testflight version inspect still available. There is workaroud way to avoid this is read the whole js file and run with JSContext method evaluateScript. There must have some build configurations to disable this.